# Adobe Flash Player Settings not show Remember button

Tags: html, flash, flex4

[image] 
I have an Adobe Flash Player Application, when the page loads it shows a popup ( the Adobe flash player settings ), but in that popup it doesn't show the **Remember** checkbox.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different kind of popup:

- The first one is displayed when then application try to access a webcam or a microphone. This one does not display a *remember* option. That the one you see in your application;
- The second one is displayed programmatically by performing a call to `Security.showSettings()`

It is good practice to open the security panel before trying to access any of the webcams / cameras / microphones of the user anyway.

In case you don't develop this application but still want to display the popup with the *remember* option, you can do so by right-clicking on it and select `Settings...`. The privacy tab should be the second one.